# problem in size when convert qt designer to python code

Tags: python, qt

When I build my app in the qt designer, everything is in order as I expected. For example, all the icons are in place as I wanted, and even in preview mode, everything is OK. But when I convert this to Python code, everything shrinks and falls apart.
Two points:

1. When I compare the sizes with the graphic program and the Python code, both are the same and it seems that the Python program works correct and displays dimensions is incorrectly in the qt designer.
2. My laptop monitor is 4K and I think this is also a problem.
   Image The thing I do when I run Python code that I see in the graphics program

[image]

Comment: How to reproduce your proble... it's so hard to do so based on your description

Comment: I have no idea, I have this problem in my laptop with resolution 3800*2400 but when I run the code in another lap top with resolution 1300*800 it's that I want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.